Unity2d Custom Made Sprites Imported In The Engine Lose Quality
I created a PNG image of slime with a size of 360x360 pixels in Krita, dragged it into Unity2D Editor, resized it to 0.3 on the X and Y axes, and it immediately got pixelized... How can I fix that?
I tried to play with different picture sizes and scaling, but it still didn't work...
Change Filler Mode to Point and it didn't help either

well how many pixels per unit are you making it? cos if you made say 100x100 pixels per unity a 0.3 sprite is 1/3 of that, and your  sprite is 3.6 units so it would be like super small

provide screenshots for context, what's your game view's resolution?
